# custom UITableViewCell with image for highlighting

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a custom UITableViewCell (instantiated from XIB) with an image as background. Now I want another image to be the background when the cell is selected (similar to the blue flashing for standard cells). I already tried setting it using `setSelectedBackgroundView` in `(void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated` or even in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` but the background for highlighting wont show up. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In your Custom Cell.xib**

[image]

**Next make this**

[image]

**And Finally do this**

[image: enter code here]

Comment: thx for explanation with images but you missed setting selectionStyle not to none.

Answer (score 2):

have you tried like below one

Call below Method From the TableView DataSource Method `(cellForAtIndexPath)` For Doing the same Task

```
 - (void)setCellBGColorNormalAndSelectedForTableViewCell:(UITableViewCell*)cell cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
  UIImageView *normalCellBG = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height)];

[normalCellBG setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"box_nonselected.png"]];//Set Image for Normal
[normalCellBG setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[cell setBackgroundView:normalCellBG];


UIImageView *selecetedCellBG = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height)];
[selecetedCellBG setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"box_selected.png"]];//Set Name for selected Cell
[selecetedCellBG setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[cell setSelectedBackgroundView:selecetedCellBG ];

 }
```

Comment: Dude i was having a same question. Your answer works well, but this method is getting called many times if we write in `cellForAtIndexPath` and images getting overridden. how to call only once ?

Answer (score 1):

You can set selected background view using the `XIB` you created for `CustomCell` . You just need to take `UIImageView` on to the that `XIB` (`imageview` must have same height as that of `CustomCell`) . Now connect the outlet naming "`selectedBackgroundView`" for that `CustomCell` to the `UIImageView` you have taken as a selected background view . Also check whether the `selectionStyle` for that `CustomCell` is not none .