# how to change the background image of the cell in didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uitableview, uiimageview

I want to change the background image of the cell when cell it is selected.

I have tried with this syntax:

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath{
 //for adding image
 cell.ImgCateg.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[ImgArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
     ...
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CRHomeCategCell *cell = (CRHomeCategCell*)[_tblCateg cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.ImgCateg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"DefaultBg.png"];
}
```

> this changes image in the foreground not in the background.

**Please help and thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set UITableviewCell's property **setSelectedBackgroundView** in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

like ,

```
- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath{
{
....
UIImageView *normalCellBG = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height)];

[normalCellBG setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"box_nonselected.png"]];//Set Image for Normal
[normalCellBG setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[cell setBackgroundView:normalCellBG];


UIImageView *selecetedCellBG = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height)];
[selecetedCellBG setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"box_selected.png"]];//Set Name for selected Cell
[selecetedCellBG setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[cell setSelectedBackgroundView:selecetedCellBG ];

}
```

look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16313924/1597744) SO question.

Comment: Your answer works well, but this method is getting called many times if we write in `cellForAtIndexPath` and images getting overridden. how to call this method only once ?

Comment: This is the just code for `setSelectedBackgroundView` of cell, you have to write proper code of creating cell like `yourcell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil){//create new}`

Comment: I wrote this but doesn't help,
        `CRHomeCategCell *cell = (CRHomeCategCell *)[_tblCateg dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];if (cell == nil)
        {NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CRHomeCategCell" owner:self options:nil];
            for (id oneObject in nib) if ([oneObject isKindOfClass:[CRHomeCategCell class]])cell = (CRHomeCategCell *)oneObject;
            [self setCellBGColorNormalAndSelectedForTableViewCell:cell cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        }cell.ImgCateg.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[ImgArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];return cell;`

Comment: @Krunal: please edit it in question so it look properly, and other may also help.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this on following way:

```
UIImage *cellImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myimage.png"];
UIImageView *cellView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:cellImage];
cellView.contentMode = UIContentViewModeScaleToFill; 
cell.backgroundView = cellView;
```